# ggvis scatter plot with 95% prediction interval

Tags: r, plot, prediction, ggvis

```
library(ggvis)
mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  layer_model_predictions(model = "lm", se = TRUE)
```

The above produces a scatter plot with a fitted regression line and 95% confidence limits on [image: f].

[image]

**Question**: How to draw a scatter plot with a fitted regression line and 95% **prediction limits** on [image: f]?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea. It probably needs more work to get exactly what you're after though.

```
mtcars.pi = data.frame(mtcars, predict(lm(mpg~wt,data=mtcars), interval="prediction"))
mtcars.pi %>% 
ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
layer_points() %>%
layer_ribbons(y=~lwr, y2=~upr, opacity:=.5) %>%
layer_model_predictions(model = "lm", se = TRUE)
```